# Store images into SQL Server

Tags: vb.net, image, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server Management Studio as my database.

I need to upload a set of images to the server in order to display them upon certain triggers in my system. I know that images can be uploaded to the server by means of conversion of the images to binary.

How can I upload the image directly to the server without coding it? Or the only way to do this is to load all the images upon startup then upload all of them into the server? Will it affect the performance of the system and lags will occur upon startup?

Comment: Have you looked into BLOBs?

Comment: BLOB stands for "Binary Large Object" and is a type of data that's designed to allow you to store large binary objects.  It would seem like this field would be a good fit for an image.  Here's a wiki page with more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But I think you got my question wrong. I mean how can I use it? How can I upload images using what you have suggested?

Comment: I understand; I just posted the BLOB reference so you could use it as a starting point for your solution, since you'd have an idea of what to google for.  Try this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/e88ae49c-23b3-4160-8138-24d089a3fee1/

Comment: What a nice reference! Thank you for this.

Comment: My pleasure.  I hope it solves your issue.